# Javascript Calendar with Drag select for multiple days

Tags: javascript, calendar

Anyone know of a Javascript Calendar that supports drag selection for multiple days? Need to be able to do it over months as well, not just restricted to one month.

Thanks a lot in advance, the ones here are no good for my problem: 
http://www.javascript-examples.com/javascript-calendars/

Answer (score 0):

a jquery datepicker

http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/datepicker/

which, although doesn't support drag, gives you the ability to get a date range for more than one month

or -even better- you can use the DatePicker component from jQuery UI 
http://ui.jquery.com/repository/latest/demos/functional/#ui.datepicker
(search for Date ranges)

Comment: This is an answer, but not to OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

This is de Best javascript Calendar i've found.
http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/